# Angular 6 with chart.js TypeError: item is null

Tags: angular-material, chart.js

I'm trying to use Chartjs in an Angular application I'm developing.

So upon changing the value of a select menu it's supposed to draw a chart according to the selected value. But I'm getting **TypeError: item is null** . I've looked everywhere and the solutions I've found did not work.

This the selecting part code :

```
<mat-form-field>
 <mat-select [(ngModel)]="selected" placeholder="Y" 
  (ngModelChange)="drawBubbleChart($event)">
     ....
 </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

This is my **html** code :

```
<div *ngIf="chart">
    <canvas #ctrx >{{ chart }}</canvas>
</div>
```

my **ts** code :

```
@ViewChild('ctrx') private chartRef;

drawBubbleChart(){
    let ds = this.prepareData();
    let chartID = this.chartRef.nativeElement.getContext("ctrx");
    let options = {
          title: {
            display: true,
            text: "Testing what's up"
          }, scales: {
            yAxes: [{ 
              scaleLabel: {
                display: true,
                labelString: "One"
              }
            }],
            xAxes: [{ 
              scaleLabel: {
                display: true,
                labelString: "Two"
              }
            }]
          }
        }
    console.log("data =>", ds);
    if (ds.length !== 0) {
        console.log("inside if !== 0");
        this.chart = new Chart(chartID,{
            type: 'bubble',
            datasets: ds,
            options: options
        });
    }
}
```

I tried `let chartID = document.getElementById("ctrx");` but it gives me a  **TypeError: item is null** as well .

How can solve this and draw a chart after selecting an option ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to not use `*ngIf`, it destroys your canvas and the ElementRef. Hide it with CSS.

Also, I use `getContext('2d')`

```html
<canvas #canvas>{{ chart }}</canvas>
```

```
@ViewChild('canvas') canvas: ElementRef;
this.canvas.nativeElement.getContext('2d')
```

Comment: `@ViewChild('canvas') canvas: ElementRef; `